# Infrared LED tracking: Using OpenCV to track x, y, z positions

Tags: opencv, image-processing, tracking

I am looking for a way to approach a computer vision problem I'm having.

I have working tracking system:

- 4-8 cameras
- Gives (x,y,z) of a infrared led
- Each led Transmits a unique 8 bit signal

The tracking system is expensive and the interface is too hard for our users to work with. I want to replace it with a possible my own/ OpenCV implementation.

My current approach which seems to require a lot of development of what seems to be common problems:

1. Calibrate the cameras to make a 3D space - The cameras need to know where they are in space and in relation to each other.
2. Given two or more camera sees a unique led it uses gray-scale image with the pixel to calculate the 3D position (x, y, z) of that led.

Right now I am attempting to write my own custom algorithm for both task and its proving to be a lot of work. Is it possible to approach this with OpenCV to help with the heavy lifting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at Free track : http://www.free-track.net/english/ you can download sources there.

Comment: This is a very promising solution to my issue. I'll look at it in more detail.

Comment: This was worth while to see but it does not fully deliver all I want. It seems to use a single camera so i might be able to modify it to use multiple cameras.